# What is Kali Linux and what does it do and why do so many people use it?

Tags: kali-linux

Why do people use Kali Linux and what is it for ? I have a Lenovo-ThinkPad laptop and tried downloading it but it didnt work.

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/906425/what-makes-kali-linux-different-from-other-linux-distros-for-it-to-be-used-exclu/1040849#1040849

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: Advice: Read [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), don't believe the hype you read in forums, and pick some other Linux distro to play around. You'll have all the hacking tools Kali has (if that's what you want), but none of the headaches (we get "I installed Kali and XYZ does not work" questions regularly). Kali is **not** "what all the hackers use".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What makes Kali Linux different from other Linux distros for it to be used exclusively for hacking and penetration testing?](https://superuser.com/questions/906425/what-makes-kali-linux-different-from-other-linux-distros-for-it-to-be-used-exclu)

Answer (score 2):

> What is Kali Linux for?

Per [kali.org](https://www.kali.org/), the home of Kali Linux, it is:

> [An] advanced [Penetration Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_test) Linux distribution used for Penetration Testing, Ethical Hacking and network security assessments.

That is to say, it is primarily aimed at people testing computer security, either professionally or recreationally.

> Why do people use Kali Linux?

My understanding is that the security focus (i.e. a lack of extraneous software for "regular" users) and the suite of security tools bundled with the distribution is often appealing to people interested in cybersecurity. It is also an evolution of [BackTrack Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BackTrack), which had a similar focus and was relatively popular in the same general community.

Answer (score 1):

Kali Linux is for penetration testing:

https://www.kali.org/

> Download Kali Linux – our most advanced penetration testing platform
> we have ever made. Available in 32 bit, 64 bit, and ARM flavors, as
> well as a number of specialized builds for many popular hardware
> platforms. Kali can always be updated to the newest version without
> the need for a new download.

I have Kali in a Virtual Machine to learn it, and I am in Kali as I post this.

For true penetration testing, it is best installed on a physical machine and then you need a wireless adapter that can use promiscuous mode.

Your ThinkPad likely does not have such wireless - my ThinkPad X1 and X230 do not. I think there may be USB wireless cards that might work.

> I have a Lenovo-ThinkPad laptop and tried downloading it but it didn't
> work.

If you wish to learn it before committing a machine to its use, you might be better off to install in in a Virtual Machine .

I have Kali in VMware on my X1 and in Hyper-V on my X230. See if your ThinkPad has and supports Hyper-V and you can download and install Kali 2020.4 for free to see what it is about.

This is the best way to start and learn.

I do not know if Kali is really widespread. I do not think so. More users would be happier with Ubuntu (which I also have here on this X1).

Good luck.

Comment: Judging from the questions we get regularly, I think the most widespread use for Kali is "I am a newbie, I want to learn hacking, and I installed Kali in a VM to do that". Which is a terrible idea, because many things are unnecessarily difficult on Kali, you can do all the hacking experiments you need with a sane distro. Also [see here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me).

Comment: If one wishes to try penetration testing, they just need a USB Wireless card that works in Kali (numerous cards do not work) and then use USB passthrough and connect by that wireless in the VM.

Comment: Penetration testing = you put Kali on a USB stick, and walk into some building to hack *their* machines. That's what Kali is made for. For Wifi hacking, *anything* is better than Kali, *in particular* because many more Wireless cards will just work out of the box. And because you can install additional stuff. Which comes in handy (I've used it). All the hacking tools are also available on other distros, if they are Debian based, even in the same way as in Kali. So using a VM with Kali to do Wifi hacking is idiotic.

Answer (score 0):

Kali Linux is a Linux distribution mainly used for penetration testing.

It's main characteristic is that it contain an important number of tools used in pentest :

- Reconnaissance tools (Maltego, TheHarvester ...)
- Network Scanner (nmap, hping ...)
- Bruteforce tools (John, Hydra...)
- Vulnerability scanner (OpenVAS, metasploit)
- ...

But most of these tools can also be installed on a classic linux distribution.

So **the main advantages of Kali Linux is that you don't have to take care about how to install penetration testing tools** once you have installed the system.

That's why it is often appreciated by beginners : it provide access to pentest tool without having to know how to install these tools.

Although Kali Linux is probably the best-known Cyber-Security distribution, there are several interesting alternative you can try.

Parrot Linux is one of these alternative.Moreover, it has the advantage to be a little more userfriendly.